# Replace \ with / on image path

Tags: javascript, regex

I get this produced path of an uploaded image:

```
'..\assets\dist\upload\avatar.jpg'
```

I'd like make it with this format.

```
'../assets/dist/upload/avatar.jpg'
```

I tried with `.replace(/[\]/g, '/');`

But didn't works with me.

Also, I consult [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript), but didn't resolve my problem.
There isn't an example about converting back slash to forward slash.

Only it's possible if we are talking about `'..\\assets\\dist\\upload\\avatar.jpg'`. But, my case is `'..\assets\dist\upload\avatar.jpg'`.

Have you please any idea about solving that ?.

Big thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Try `.replace(/\\/g, '/')`

Comment: Hello @ischenkodv, thanks a lot for your reply. that didn't workd with me

Comment: Hello Sir @Reactgular, thanks for your reply. But that link can't resolve my problem. All the examples are for string not containing slashs.

Comment: @Laura there is a big difference between `'..\assets\dist\upload\avatar.jpg'` and `'..\\assets\\dist\\upload\\avatar.jpg'` in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes Sir, I totally agree, but in that thread I didn't found an example how convert `'..\assets\dist\upload\avatar.jpg'` to `'../assets/dist/upload/avatar.jpg'`. Only I found how convert `'..\\assets\\dist\\upload\\avatar.jpg'` to `'../assets/dist/upload/avatar.jpg'`. Have you please any suggestions?. Big thanks Sir.

Comment: @Laura open the JavaScript file in a text editor and manually add an extra `\\` to each string that uses only one of them.

Comment: Ok Sir @Reactgular, thanks, but what about case of using dynamic path, so I can't made change manually ?. I have to convert directly without manual intervention ?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to made change on backend.
So you have that format `'..\\assets\\dist\\upload\\avatar.jpg'`.
On frontend try to use `.replace(/[\\]/g, '/')`
So yo got `'../assets/dist/upload/avatar.jpg'`

HTH